# ValueError: X has 5 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 2607 features as input

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

This is how i am converting text to count vector.

```
cv1 = CountVectorizer()
x_traincv=cv1.fit_transform(x_train)
a = x_traincv.toarray()
a
```

this the model using for predict.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC
rfc_b = RFC()
rfc_b.fit(a,y_train)
y_pred = rfc_b.predict(a)
```

this is how i am using the live details to predict

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

document = ["Single Hargrave France Female Graduation",]

# Create a Vectorizer Object
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

vectorizer.fit(document)


print("Vocabulary: ", vectorizer.vocabulary_)



vector = vectorizer.transform(document)


print("Encoded Document is:")
print(vector.toarray())
```

I AM NOW USING THE MODEL TO PREDICT.

```
rfc_b.predict(vector)
```

THE ERROR I AM GETTING

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-7cc301d916e6> in <module>()
----> 1 rfc_b.predict(vector)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    399         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
    400             raise ValueError(
--> 401                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    402                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    403             )

ValueError: X has 5 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 2607 features as input.
```

IT IS WORKING FINE WHEN WORKING WITH TEST SET, DID GET THE OUTPUT.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('Train accuracy score:',accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred))
print('Test accuracy score:', accuracy_score(y_test,rfc_b.predict(b)))

Train accuracy score: 0.987375
Test accuracy score: 0.773
```

BUT NOT WHEN I USE THE ABOUVE TO INPUT A SINGLE INPUT TO CHECK THE OUTPUT

Comment: What's the shape of x_traincv?

Comment: this is the shape.
(8000, 2607)

Answer (score 1):

You have to store your vectorizer used during training, and just call .transform on it, if you create a new one you lose meaning of dimensions used during training, and in particular - you lack many of them, but your vectorizer has no idea about this (as it only has access to your one sample).

```
cv1 = CountVectorizer()
x_traincv=cv1.fit_transform(x_train)
a = x_traincv.toarray()

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC
rfc_b = RFC()
rfc_b.fit(a,y_train)
y_pred = rfc_b.predict(a)

document = ["Single Hargrave France Female Graduation",]


vector = cv1.transform(document)


print("Encoded Document is:")
print(vector.toarray())
rfc_b.predict(vector)
```